# Reloading python function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using a jupyter lab notebook and trying to modify code, reload it within the jupyter notebook and use the modified code without reloading the kernel. I am using python 3.5.5 and am running code like this:

(in file test.py)

```
def myTest():
    print('hello')
```

(in jupyter)

```
from test import myTest
import importlib
importlib.reload(test)
myTest()
```

When I run the code in my jupyter lab notebook I get a NameError that `name 'test' is not defined`. From searching on stackoverflow the only references I find to this error is problems using older version of python. But the way I am using `importlib.reload()` seems to be correct.

Comment: Where are you defining `test`? `myTest` appears to be defined

Comment: maybe you did `from test import myTest`.

Comment: right sorry forgot that part; fixed the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried the built-in magic command [`autoreload`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html)?

At the beginning of your notebook, add:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```